# The new volume group's Format do not be checked

Tags: linux, centos, disk

When I install CentOS 6 system on my physical server, there are two disks, you see the `sda` and `sdb`, I created the `VolGroup00` vg, you can see my snapshot:

[image]

there I have a question, you see the sda2's VolGroup's `Format` is checked, why the sdb1's `Format` is not check?

What's this meaning of `Format`?  why the VolGroup00's Format do not be check?

Comment: loicaly you format logic volumes only I think volgroup should not have the format checked.. (sda2)

Comment: why the sda2(VolGroup) have been checked the Format?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the installer internally handles the "Format" checkmark on LVM physical volumes.

If the installer "thinks" running `pvcreate` on the partition is the LVM equivalent of "formatting" on physical volumes (which would make sense), then this might indicate it detects a previously-created LVM physical volume header already existing on `sdb1`, and so won't overwrite it unless you explicitly tell it to.

Or perhaps you simply forgot to check/accidentally unchecked the setting to format `sdb1` in the dialog you used to define `sdb1` as a LVM physical volume?

Or perhaps you found a minor display bug in the installer?